# vs code "launcher[1] disconnected unexpected" : how do i fix it?

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, debugging

Visual Studio Code was working well...
but suddenly this error message started to show up when debugging a python code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BrEc.png)
I tried updating windows and fully uninstalling Visual studio, but it didn't help.

following is a repeat:
Visual Studio Code was working well...
but suddenly this error message started to show up when debugging a python code

I tried updating windows and fully uninstalling Visual studio, but it didn't help.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, **error messages**, etc. —copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Comment: possibly a regression. see https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/327. Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Include also the version number of your Python extension and your Python Debugger extension.

Comment: If you raise an issue ticket in the debugpy github repo, please ping me with a link to it.